# how use average function based in two differents dataset fields ssrs if one depend from the other one

Tags: reporting-services, report

im working with report that visual studio 2010 have, then i have a chart series with four fields planta, date, and densidad, i have to get the average of all the data that densidad has but only when the date is the same for example

### Date                         Densidad

11/05/2015                     2
11/05/2015                     3
12/05/2015                     4

in this case i have two data from 11/05/2015 the only for that date i must get the average that in this case should be 2,5 , ive been looking for an expression that works but i ve found anything, please?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new row group, then go to the group's properties and group by date. In your tablix, add in AVG(Yourdataset!Yourvalue.Value) next to the date. This should group by date.

Your group expression should look like this:
=FormatDateTime(Fields!dates.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate)